# Change CRM Outlook setting for creating Contacts (Script)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to disable the setting in the CRM for Outlook client that automatically creates a Contact if one doesn't already exist. This can be changed in the settings screen on the client machine. However, I have many hundreds of machines to change and cannot find a policy or script that would accomplish this.

Is there any supported way to change this setting in bulk (powershell, script)? If it is a registry modification, does anyone know where this information is kept?

Thanks for any pointers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of tools you can use to update user settings. One of those should hopefully change the setting you need.

- [CRM2011 User Settings Utility](http://crm2011usersettings.codeplex.com/)
- [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the links - unfortunately they are no use for this setting. I find it bizarre there is no easy way to do this. I am finding blog posts trying to do the same thing dating back to 2007!

Comment: Are you sure? Go to, http://crm2011usersettings.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CRM2011%20User%20Settings%20Utility%20%202.0 look at the first screen shot seems to have a setting for emails highlighted

Comment: I'm blind is the problem. Thanks a lot :-)